# Images resetting upon entering frame 1 (flash/actionscript 3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In frame one I have buttons that send the player to different frames.  There is a button that sends to a 'how to play' frame and then from that frame a back button to the main menu.  The problem is that I have clouds floating in the background that I animated with actionscript.  Going to the 'how to play' page is fine, but when I hit back, the clouds freeze and new ones are created.  I had everything on frame 1, but thought maybe since it was going back to the first frame it was resetting everything, so now I have the back button sending the player to a new keyframe on frame 2 but the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any code you have on frame 1 will be run again when you return to frame 1.

I'm assuming you have code there that creates the clouds.

> Solution: Create the clouds on frame 1 and continue to frame 2. Create the buttons on frame 2. When you hit 'back', return to frame 2 rather than frame 1.